# Various variations of the implementation of dfs

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Suppose I have the concrete undirected graph:
"1----2----3----4".

What is the difference between the next implementations of the algorithm **"dfs"**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maxSize=4000;
vector<int> graph[maxSize];
bool visited0[maxSize];
void dfs0(int firstPoint, int previousPoint)
{
    visited0[firstPoint]=true;
    for(int secondPoint : graph[firstPoint])
    {
        if(visited0[secondPoint]==false)
        {
            dfs0(secondPoint, firstPoint);
        }
    }
    return;
}
bool visited1[maxSize];
void dfs1(int firstPoint, int previousPoint)
{
    visited1[maxSize]=true;
    for(int secondPoint : graph[firstPoint])
    {
        if(secondPoint==previousPoint)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dfs1(secondPoint, firstPoint);
    }
    return;
}
bool visited2[maxSize];
void dfs2(int firstPoint, int previousPoint)
{
    visited2[firstPoint]=true;
    for(int secondPoint : graph[firstPoint])
    {
        if(secondPoint==previousPoint)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(visited2[secondPoint]==false)
        {
            dfs2(secondPoint, firstPoint);
        }
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    dfs0(1, -1);
    dfs1(1, -1);
    dfs2(1, -1);
    return 0;
}
```

If it is more precisely I want to know when (in which cases) I should use the commands-branchings:

```
if(visited0[secondPoint]==false)
{
    dfs0(secondPoint, firstPoint);        (Variation #1)
}
```

and

```
if(secondPoint==previousPoint)
{
    continue;
}
dfs1(secondPoint, firstPoint);        (Variation #2)
```

and

```
if(secondPoint==previousPoint)
{
    continue;
}
if(visited2[secondPoint]==false)
{
    dfs2(secondPoint, firstPoint);        (Variation #3)
}
```

Please, describe each variation (Variation #1, Variation #2, Variation #3).

In which cases must I use **Variation #1**?

In which cases must I use **Variation #2**?

In which cases must I use **Variation #3**?

How will the appearence of the next command-branching (it is placed below) influence on the various implementations of the algorithm **"dfs"** (dfs0(1, -1), dfs1(1, -1), dfs2(1, -1)):

```
Use the parameter "visited" in dependence of the version of the algorithm "dfs": either "visited0", or "visited1", or "visited2".

How is it important to use this command-branching at the beginning of the various implementations of the algorithm "dfs" (dfs0(1, -1), dfs1(1, -1), dfs2(1, -1))?

if(visited0[firstPoint]==true)
{
    return;
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no logical difference between **Variation 1** and **Variation 3**, but **Variation 3** is optimised version as it will **avoid** unwanted recursive calls which might be a great deal if **large** test cases are involved. This might consume more memory unnecessarily.

The **Variation 2** differs logically from the other two variations, becuase, it allows a node to be visited multiple times during DFS.

The number of times the node gets visited in the **Variation 2** will depend on the adjacency matrix/list of the graph.

Using the **command-branching** in **Variation 1** and **Variation 3**, will have no effect, as we are already checking if the node has been visited before, but it will surely make the **Variation 2** work correctly (as per the definition of DFS: visit every node almost once.)